# Spring does not recognize Multipartfile

Tags: spring

File upload with spring gives

```
WARN  DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Handler execution resulted in exception: Required MultipartF
ile parameter 'file' is not present
```

Uploading controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                                                 @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name)));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return "You successfully uploaded " + name + "!";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }
```

Javascript

```
var form = document.getElementById('the-form');
            form.onsubmit = function() {
                var formData = new FormData(form);

                formData.append('name', "asdasdasd");
                formData.append('file', file);

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                // Add any event handlers here...
                xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'), true);
                xhr.send(formData);

                return false; // To avoid actual submission of the form
            }
```

Application context

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="8000000"/>
    </bean>
```

Work fine when I send just parameters string, ints etc. But breaks with multipart file.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

EDIT
Here is the form

```
<form id="the-form" method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input name="file" type="file">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </form>
```

File variable

```
lastModified: 1444832093455
lastModifiedDate: Wed Oct 14 2015 17:14:53 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
name: "file"
size: 89
type: ""
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Comment: For starters send it as a proper multipart request, I see nothing that switchers the content to do so.

Comment: What do you mean by proper multipart request?

Comment: just as I say it there is a difference with a plain form or a multipart form the content-type differs. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4. I nowhere see that set to the proper content type when submitting the form.

Comment: Sorry did not include that, content-type is multipart/form-data

Comment: I would say adding the `file` is wrong. What does `file` refer to in your javascript? I would expect something like `document.getElementById('file').files[0]`.

Comment: File object has the chosen file in it but I get the same error.

Comment: Don't assume please add the code as you use to the question. Currently you only have snippets you deem relevant but they do not contain sufficient information.

Comment: When I console.log the file variable I get the file so it's included (see edit)

Comment: Take a look at this, if it helps.

Comment: @RossiRobinsion you forgot to add the link, but the problem is solved now. Commons file upload read and emptied!? the file before spring boot got to it. So I removed commons.

Comment: I am glad your were able to solve. My apology, I forgot to put the link.